# Direcionar para outra página externa Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theme

COlegas.

Estou tentando mexer no Wordpress e confesso que estou levando uma surra enorme. Tenho que criar mais um item no menu no gerenciador do Wordpress ( wp-admin ) e vi que tenho que criar, se não me engano, dentro do arquivo functions.php, porém não estou sabendo como criar. Tenho um modelo que foi criado pelo colega anteriormente que fez dessa forma:

```
/************ ALBUM REGISTER***********/

add_action('init', 'album_register');
register_taxonomy('album', 'album', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Categorias de Album', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true));
function album_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('album', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('album', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Adicionar Album', 'Vereador'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar Album'),
        'edit_item' => __('Editar Album'),
        'new_item' => __('Adicionar Album'),
        'view_item' => __('Visualizar Album'),
        'search_items' => __('Procurar Album'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        //'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/imagens/vereadores.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      );
    register_post_type( 'album' , $args );
}
/************ END ALBUM REGISTER***********/
```

Como eu faria para criar um item chamado contracheques e direcionar para a página contracheques.php?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se for para criar no menu principal do admin é só usar algo parecido com isto:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'My Top Level Menu Example', 'Top Level Menu', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/myplugin-admin-page.php', 'myplguin_admin_page', 'dashicons-tickets', 6  );
}
```

Comment: Coloquei esse código, mas agora todas as ´páginas aparecem 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_menu_page() in /cmni.rj.gov.br/www/wp-content/themes/website/functions.php on line 92 e não consigo editar o functions.php. COmo eu faria para corrigir isso?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos esse código é um exemplo da funcionalidade. É de suma importancia que tenha acesso ao ftp para esta alteração. Vale tambem verificar se este código funciona na sua versão do wordpres e verificar se foi colocado no local certo.

Comment: Tenho acesso ao FTP. Como eu faria para corrigir?

Comment: abrir o arquivo e remover o codigo

Comment: Perfeito Otto. Consegui. Obrigado. Em relação ao seu código, me desculpe, é que sou leigo no assunto. O erro que deu foi em relação a esse método add_menu_page().

Comment: @Jose.Marcos se você verificar no codex do wordpress ele dia para utilizar desta forma. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page você esta utilizando uma versao atualizada ? E tambem todo teste de implementação de código faça em uma instalação a parte para não ter estes problemas

Comment: O WP é 3.3.2. Esse sistema já existia aqui na empresa. A pessoa implementou, mas depois saiu e estamos com dificuldades de mexer, pois não conhecemos muito WP.